# Why do I get this undefined in property error when trying to save to database in Firebase?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-realtime-database

I Have written code which should allow the user to upload an image to the database in firebase. The code basically references the node 'images and then sets the image into the child node url. However I get the below message.

```
Firebase.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'images.url'
```

Any clues as to why this is happening? My code is below.

```
var theBigWeddingBook = angular.module('theBigWeddingBook');

theBigWeddingBook.controller('WeddingBookCtrl', function($scope, $firebase, Upload) {

    var ref= new Firebase('https://the-big-wedding-book.firebaseio.com/');
    var images = $scope.file;

    $scope.submit = function() {
        ref.child('images').set({url : images}).then(function(url) {
            console.log('Image Uploaded!');
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the value of your images var?

Comment: The value is the image that is loaded through the ng file upload form... So it is 'ng-model="images"'

Comment: Firebase doesn't support images but you can save them if you convert the image to a base64 string.

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

I Have now refactored my code, which stops me from getting the error.

```
theBigWeddingBook.controller('WeddingBookCtrl', function($scope, $firebaseArray, $firebaseAuth, $location, Upload) {

    var ref= new Firebase('https://the-big-wedding-book.firebaseio.com/images');
    var auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);

    ref.onAuth(function(authData) {
      if (authData) {
        console.log("Authenticated with uid:", authData.uid, authData);
        $location.path("/your-wedding-book");
      } else {
        console.log("Client unauthenticated.")
      }
    });

    $scope.post = $firebaseArray(ref);

    $scope.submit = function() {
        Upload.base64DataUrl($scope.image).then(function(base64Urls) {
                $scope.post.$add({
                    text: $scope.comment,
                    image: $scope.image
                }).then(function(text) {
                    console.log('Post Added');
                }).catch(function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                })
        });
    };
});
```

The post is now being added, however the image although it says it is being uploaded... it isnt... Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong in this aspect?